# Python serial.write doing nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

Basically, what I am trying to do is input a string to the Arduino from Python, and the Arduino should print it back, and again it is read from Python. But when I run this code nothing happens.

I have tried the Arduino code separately and it works well with the serial monitor. I checked if the problem was with `readline()` with a different problem and it was running perfectly, so I guess the problem is with `write()`.

This is my Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

char rx_byte = 0;

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    rx_byte = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(rx_byte);
  }
}
```

This is my Python code:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
ser.write(b's')
ser.flush()
time.sleep(1)    
message = ser.readline()
print(message)    
ser.close()
```

Comment: does the arduino terminal indicate that that code is working?

Comment: @Dan Steingart yes i have run the code separately in arduino and input from serial monitor and it worked only in python nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I think the `ser.flush()` might be killing the response. When I run your code without it my code works fine.

Comment: sorry but even without ser.flush() my code is not working

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing

`message = ser.readline()`

to

`message = ser.read()`

and everything worked for me. Try using `read()` instead of `readline()`

Comment: actually i dont have a problem with ser.readline my problem is with ser.write

Answer (score -1):

You should check [Arduino - Available](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available), because that if is `Serial.available() > 0` you missed a ()

Comment: sorry my bad i typed it wrongly in the question, but in the actual code i have used the brackets

Comment: Well, i would try check that import serial, check if you got the pyserial installed.

Comment: well ser.readline() is working separately as i mentioned so it is installed